# What are the craters on the moon with peaks in the middle of them?

Tags: the-moon, crater

Was taking some extremely amatuer pictures of the moon from my cheap telescope with my camera phone...

[image]

You see the crater Im talking about? Top right.The one with a little nub in the middle- which Im sure is actually massive. How was this formed differently than the other craters? What couldve caused the hill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice picture! Those peaks are actually a very common feature in craters formed by large impacts. Craters with these features are known as "[complex craters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_crater)". Basically what happens is that when the meteor hits, it pushes in the surface. Then the underlying mantle produces an "elastic rebound" and pushes outwards. This is a similar effect to what happens when you hit a drum. Your drumstick rebounds off the drum, and the drum begins to vibrate. Since rock (even molten rock) is much more dense than a drumskin, it does not vibrate very much. The vibrations solidify, resulting in a crater with one central peak.

How exactly this happens is still being investigated. [This paper](http://www.planetary.brown.edu/pdfs/4779.pdf) provides a pretty good explanation of what happens, but it's quite technical.

[image]

Even larger impacts will produce [ring structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ring_(crater)). These are relatively rare on the Earth, since such structures are quickly weathered away. A good example of this is the Chicxulub crater off the Yucatan peninsula (the impact that killed the dinosaurs).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extremely comprehensive answer. Is there a certain size class of asteroid where these would be more common? I dont usually see these on the smaller craters- assuming because it sidnt get deep enough to deform the required mantle layer? So I guess the question would be how thick is the crust usually on the moon?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Unfortunately, I do not know what the cutoff is. But I know that it depends on both the size of the impactor and the structure of the crust and mantle. A more fluid crust and mantle would be more elastic, and a larger impactor would provide more energy.

Comment: Haha given the bumpy and chaotic gravitational field of the moon knowing the average crust depth would be a chore Im sure- thanks for the clarification regardless.

Answer (score 4):

That is the rebound effect. Just like a rock falling into a pond causes a big ripple and a big drop to jump out in the center, the same happens with a rock striking the Moon.

Refer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26091/how-does-the-central-peak-in-moon-craters-form) astrophysics stackexchange for more information.

Comment: Great analogy but rofl that name dude- planning any trips to Uranus to destroy it too?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn best. lmaoing. comment. ever.